# Zapier - why is bundle.inputData formatted differently to inputFields? Nested children are added twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

We have a Zapier app, which has a "createContact" action. I have defined the fields that our users will see in Zapier's UI, via the `inputFields` array. This includes some fields nested within fields.

My code produces the desired UI, but when I create a zap and test it, the data that I receive isn't formatted in the same way. The nested fields are added twice.

Here's the exported object:

```
module.exports = {
  key: 'contact',
  noun: 'Contact',
  create: {
    display: {
      label: 'Create Contact',
      description: 'Creates a new contact.'
    },
    operation: {
      inputFields: [
        {key: 'firstName', required: true},
        {key: 'lastName', required: true},
        {key: 'middleNames', required: false},
        {key: 'address', required: false},
        {key: 'phoneNumbers', required: false},
        {key: 'emails', required: false},
        {key: 'tags', required: false},
        {key: 'links', required: false},
        { 
          key: 'education', children: [
            {key: 'school', required: false},
            {key: 'degree', required: false},
            {key: 'program', required: false, label: 'Field of Study'},
            {key: 'grade', required: false},
            {key: 'startDate', required: false, type: 'datetime' },
            {key: 'endDate', required: false, type: 'datetime' },
          ] 
        }
      ],
      perform: createContact
    },
  },

  sample: {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Test first name',
    lastName: 'Test last name'
  },

  outputFields: [
    {key: 'id', label: 'ID'},
    {key: 'firstName', label: 'First Name'},
    {key: 'lastName', label: 'Last Name'},
  ]
};
```

Note: I have followed Zapier's docs on the [Field Schema](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-schema/build/schema.html#fieldschema), which shows that this is the required format:
`{ key: 'abc', children: [ { key: 'abc' } ] }`

By putting `z.console.log(bundle.inputData)` inside the createContact function, you can see that the keys in the children array (i.e. startDate, school, etc.) have been added in 2 places:

```
== Log
inputData 2  { startDate: '15/01/2017',
  school: 'ABC School',
  endDate: '16/01/2017',
  degree: 'Test degree',
  firstName: 'Joe',
  grade: '1st',
  lastName: 'Bloggs',
  program: 'Test program',
  education:
   [ { startDate: '2017-01-15T00:00:00+00:00',
       school: 'ABC School',
       endDate: '2017-01-16T00:00:00+00:00',
       degree: 'Test degree',
       grade: '1st',
       program: 'Test program' } ],
  emails: 'test@test.com' }
== Version
1.0.0
== Step
7f944f0f-fd96-4ad3-bbc2-1d11b9b15c6f
== Timestamp
2018-01-15T12:09:56-06:00
```

According to [the Zapier docs](https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-cli/#bundleinputdata):

> `bundle.inputData` is user-provided data for this particular run of the trigger/search/create, as defined by the inputFields.

So I would expect bundle.inputData to be of the same format as inputFields. Any ideas how I can get bundle.inputData to be in the format that I've defined in inputFields?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mind updating the question with your whole action? the whole exported object. It really helps get context for what's going on!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question :)

Answer (score 2):

bundle.inputData is used to store the data.
you need to add this in your perform section :

`firstname: bundle.inputData.firstname`

whenever user will provide 'firstname:' it will be stored in firstname using `bundle.inputData`.